# Create a controller instance: Call to a member function getModule() on a non-object

Tags: php, unit-testing, module, yii2

I want to test actions of the controller in the Unit test, as described here: [yii controller action unit testing without selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338084/yii-controller-action-unit-testing-without-selenium). Optional; I know that this is done by using functional tests. Just interesting to try this approach.

For that I need to create the controller instance:

```
$controller = new SomeController('SomeController', Yii::$app->getModule('somemodule'));
```

As a result of executing this code I get the error:

> **Fatal error**: Call to a member function getModule() on a non-object in
>   C:\projects\ais\tests\codeception\backend\unit\SomeControllerTest.php
>   on line 27

How to create a controller instance in the Unit test (and in general)?

Comment: I think you should use Yii::app() not Yii::$app try it.

Comment: You obtaion a null value from the funtcion getModule('somemodule') are you sure somemodule is a  proper module name?